# Hibernate | @Transactional | @OneToMany Why? while inserting data in DB, the oneToMany field from returned entity is null for the each new entry

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-onetomany

Recently I was debugging my production code and I got to know that for each new entry(having oneToMany field as null) in Mysql using hibernate as ORM and @Transactional enabled, the returned entity has oneToMany field as null. But When I try to update the same entry, the returned entity will have oneToMany field as empty.

Comment: What is the difference between an empty reference and a null reference?

Comment: null =. No memory while
empty = memory assigned but no content